# Multiple conditions to filter a result set using Java 8

Tags: java, filter, java-8

I am looking for some help in converting some code I have to use the really nifty Java 8 Stream library. Essentially I have a bunch of student objects and I would like to get back a list of filtered objects as seen below:

```
List<Integer> classRoomList;
Set<ScienceStudent> filteredStudents = new HashSet<>();

//Return only 5 students in the end
int limit = 5;
for (MathStudent s : mathStudents)
{
    // Get the scienceStudent with the same id as the math student
    ScienceStudent ss = scienceStudents.get(s.getId());
    if (classRoomList.contains(ss.getClassroomId()))
    {
        if (!exclusionStudents.contains(ss))
        {
            if (limit > 0)
            {
                filteredStudents.add(ss);
                limit--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course the above is a super contrived example I made up for the sake of learning more Java 8. Assume all students are extended from a Student object with `studentId` and `classRoomId`. An additional requirement I would require is the have the result be an Immutable set.

Comment: This is not a code that can be easily compiled without the actual classes and state. Why don't you create a minimal, compact and verifiable example of what you're having specific problem with? There is a `filter` operator for streams, I don't think it can get any clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quite literal translation (and the required classes to play around)

```
interface ScienceStudent {
    String getClassroomId();
}
interface MathStudent {
    String getId();
}

Set<ScienceStudent> filter(
        Collection<MathStudent> mathStudents,
        Map<String, ScienceStudent> scienceStudents,
        Set<ScienceStudent> exclusionStudents,
        List<String> classRoomList) {

    return mathStudents.stream()
            .map(s -> scienceStudents.get(s.getId()))
            .filter(ss -> classRoomList.contains(ss.getClassroomId()))
            .filter(ss -> !exclusionStudents.contains(ss))
            .limit(5)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());

}
```

Multiple conditions to filter really just translate into multiple `.filter` calls or a combined big filter like `ss -> classRoomList.contains(ss.getClassroomId()) && !exclusion...`

Regarding immutable set: You best wrap that around the result manually because `collect` expects a mutable collection that can be filled from the stream and returned once finished. I don't see an easy way to do that directly with streams.

---

The `null` paranoid version

```
    return mathStudents.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull) // math students could be null
            .map(MathStudent::getId).filter(Objects::nonNull) // their id could be null
            .map(scienceStudents::get).filter(Objects::nonNull) // and the mapped science student
            .filter(ss -> classRoomList.contains(ss.getClassroomId()))
            .filter(ss -> !exclusionStudents.contains(ss))
            .limit(5)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: You missed out the bit about `exclusionStudents`.

Comment: How does this stream flow deal with potentially null values at each step?

Comment: @JohnBaum would crash with a NPE, add `.filter(Objects::nonNull)` into the chain to prevent that. (twice, once for mathStudents if they are null, then after mapping to ScienceStudents)

Comment: This is just for my info, but if I were to have multiple mappings, would I have to have that null checking filter after each mapping to guard against NPE?

Comment: @JohnBaum sure. Anytime the resulting stream of one operation can contain `null` and one of the following step something like `nullable -> nullable.dereference()` happens. Just like when you would iterate manually over the elements of the stream.